# Why is GMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate returning two street numbers for a single coordinate?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Using GMSGeocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate (firstResult or results) returns a GMSAddress for which addressline1 is something like "1400-1402 Thimbleberry Drive". I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.2.30010.0.

How can I get just "1400 ThimbleBerry Drive"? The lot size is approx. 7500 sq ft. Ideally I'd like the correct address - not the range.

Previously my application was relying on this to return a single address and it worked fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The location returned by Google's Geocoder can be of different types:

- "ROOFTOP": a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate down to street address precision.
- "RANGE_INTERPOLATED": an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
- "GEOMETRIC_CENTER": the geometric center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
- "APPROXIMATE" indicates that the returned result is approximate.

Whenever the Google Geocoding API cannot return ROOFTOP geocodes it might return a RANGE_INTERPOLATED result. So you should expect both types in the responses.

In the Reverse Geocoding Web Service there is a field that specifies the [location_type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) from which you could be able to verify that the obtained result is actually a ROOFTOP.

The iOS SDK do not expose this field. If you would like to have the same for the iOS SDK you may add a feature request by following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188833&template=787421)